# Why method from sub class is called when invoked from super class?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

My code looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass{
  public void update() {
      //...
  }

  public void somethingHappenedSoCallUpdate() {
      update();
  }
}

public class ExtendingClass extends BaseClass{
  @Override
  public void update() {
      //...
  }
}
```

There's an instance of `ExtendingClass` and at some point method `somethingHappenedSoCallUpdate()` is called. And I expect the method will call `BaseClass.update()` but `ExtendingClass.update()` is called. Can someone explain why?

Comment: In Java methods are virtual. Look up what that means.

Comment: [What is overriding?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding)

Comment: "I expect the method will call BaseClass.update()" - Why??

Comment: because the somethingHappenedSoCallUpdate method is defined in base class only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hyde said, Java methods are virtual, thats means that the VM decides at runtime which method to invoke. If you call `somethingHappenedSoCallUpdate()` on an instance that extends `BaseClass` then `BaseClass.somethingHappenedSoCallUpdate()` will be called, but since `ExtendingClass` is overriding `BaseClass.update()` it will class `ExtendingClass.update()` instead of `BaseClass.update()`.

When extending a method you have to think of it like this:
whenever you extend a method you put it on a stack and when you invoke it, Java will look on this "stack" and invokes the topmost. That means if you have a `BaseClass` that has a `update()` method, this class can be extended by X classes not overriding the `update()` method but if the X+1 class does, Java will always call that method of X+1.

Answer (score 1):

> And I expect the method will call `BaseClass.update()` but `ExtendingClass.update()` is called. Can someone explain why?

Because that's how Java is defined. By default, all non-`private` methods are *virtual*, which means that when you have overridden methods, the method that gets called on an instance is the instance's most-overridden version (`ExtendingClass`'s, in your case), regardless of the type reference through which the method call is made. This is fundamental to polymorphism in modern OOP languages.

The compile-time type reference tells the compiler whether code has access to the method; the runtime type of the object tells the JVM which override of the method to call.

Let's take a simple example:

```
class Base {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Base#method1");
    }
}
class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Derived#method1");
    }

    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("Derived#method1");
    }
}

// Usage:
Base b = new Derived();
b.method1(); // Calls Derived#method1, the most-overridden version the
             // actual object has
b.method2(); // Fails to compile; Base doesn't define method2, so the
             // code doesn't have access to call it when using a Base
             // reference, even though the object does have the method
```

Answer (score 0):

It's polymorphism:the right method is called at runtime depending on the real type of the object it's a dynamic binding.

Answer (score 0):

You overrode the method so if you still want the code in the abstract class to run you need to implicitly call `update()` within the overridden method. So...

```
public class ExtendingClass extends BaseClass {

  @Override
  public void update() {

      super.update(); // Call the base method.
  }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you overrode update in subclass and since java methods are virtual overridden version is called.

### Option #1

Override update, override `somethingHappenedSoCallUpdate()` method and use there `super.update()` instead of `update()`.

### Option #2

Make update private in superclass:

```
private void update()
```